# Error con las ventanas modales en Django

Tags: javascript, html, python, django

He estado intentando hacer un modal para inactivar a un proveedor de mi modelo y no me ha servido a pesar de seguir los pasos de mi tutor en un curso de udemy. También estuve viendo otra solución a este problema en otra pregunta ([url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25757968/bootstrap-modal-is-not-a-function)), intenté lo que mencionan e igualmente seguí obteniendo el mismo error. Este es el error que me sale:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Así es como tengo mis scripts en mi archivo base:

```
<!-- jQuery -->
      <script src=" {% static 'lib/adminlte-3.1.0/plugins/jquery/jquery.min.js' %} "></script>
      <!-- Bootstrap 4 -->
      <script src=" {% static 'lib/adminlte-3.1.0/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js' %} "></script>
      <!-- overlayScrollbars -->
      <script src=" {% static 'lib/adminlte-3.1.0/plugins/overlayScrollbars/js/jquery.overlayScrollbars.min.js' %} "></script>
      <!-- AdminLTE App -->
      <script src=" {% static 'lib/adminlte-3.1.0/js/adminlte.min.js' %} "></script>
      <!-- AdminLTE for demo purposes -->
      <script src=" {% static 'lib/adminlte-3.1.0/js/demo.js' %} "></script>
      <!-- SweetAlert -->
      <!--<script src=" {% static 'lib/sweetalert2-9.10.0/sweetalert2.all.min.js' %} "></script> 
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@10"></script>-->

      <!-- Mascaras -->
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.10/jquery.mask.js"></script>

      <!-- DataTables  & Plugins -->
      <script src=" {% static 'lib/adminlte-3.1.0/plugins/datatables/jquery.dataTables.min.js' %} "></script>
      <script src=" {% static 'lib/adminlte-3.1.0/plugins/datatables-bs4/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js' %} "></script>
      <script src=" {% static 'lib/adminlte-3.1.0/plugins/datatables-responsive/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js' %} "></script>
      <script src=" {% static 'lib/adminlte-3.1.0/plugins/datatables-responsive/js/responsive.bootstrap4.min.js' %} "></script>
      <script src=" {% static 'lib/adminlte-3.1.0/plugins/datatables-buttons/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js' %} "></script>
      <script src=" {% static 'lib/adminlte-3.1.0/plugins/datatables-buttons/js/buttons.bootstrap4.min.js' %} "></script>
      <script src=" {% static 'lib/adminlte-3.1.0/plugins/jszip/jszip.min.js' %} "></script>
      <script src=" {% static 'lib/adminlte-3.1.0/plugins/pdfmake/pdfmake.min.js' %} "></script>
      <script src=" {% static 'lib/adminlte-3.1.0/plugins/pdfmake/vfs_fonts.js' %} "></script>
      <script src=" {% static 'lib/adminlte-3.1.0/plugins/datatables-buttons/js/buttons.html5.min.js' %} "></script>
      <script src=" {% static 'lib/adminlte-3.1.0/plugins/datatables-buttons/js/buttons.print.min.js' %} "></script>
      <script src=" {% static 'lib/adminlte-3.1.0/plugins/datatables-buttons/js/buttons.colVis.min.js' %} "></script>
      
      {% block javascript %}
        
      {% endblock javascript %}

      
      {% block control_modal %}
        <script>
          function abrir_modal(url)
          {
            
            $("#popup").load(url, function(){
              $(this).modal({
                backdrop:'static',
                keyboard: false
              })
              $(this).modal('show');
            });
            return false;
          }

          function cerrar_modal()
          {
            $('#popup').modal('hide');
            return false;
          }
        </script>
      {% endblock control_modal %}
```

Asi es como tengo definida mi función para desactivar un proveedor:

```
def proveedor_inactivar(request, id):
    proveedor = Proveedor.objects.filter(pk=id).first()
    contexto ={}
    template_name= "compras/deletes/proveedor_inactivar.html"
    if not proveedor:
        return redirect("Compras:proveedor_list")
    
    if request.method == 'GET':
        contexto={'object':proveedor}

    if request.method == 'POST':
        proveedor.estado=False
        proveedor.save()
        return redirect("Compras:proveedor_list")

    return render(request,template_name,contexto)
```

Estas son mis urls (no incluyo las librerias importadas):

```
app_name='Compras'

urlpatterns = [
    path('proveedores/', ProveedorView.as_view(), name="proveedor_list"),
    path('proveedores/nuevo', ProveedorCreate.as_view(), name="proveedor_create"),
    path('proveedores/editar/<int:pk>', ProveedorUpdate.as_view(), name="proveedor_update"),
    path('proveedores/inactivar/<int:id>', proveedor_inactivar, name="proveedor_inactivar"),
    ]
```

Este es mi html para inactivar el proveedor (esta completo):

```
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="col-6">
            <div class="card card-danger">
                <form method="POST"> {% csrf_token %}
                    <div class="card-header">
                    <h3 class="card-title">Estas a punto de <b class="text-danger">inactivar</b> el registro {{ object }}!</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        
                        <div>
                            <h5><i class="icon fas fa-ban"></i> <strong>Alerta!</strong></h5>
                            Estas a punto de inactivar el item <strong>{{object}}</strong> de la lista 
                            ¿Estás seguro que deseas inactivar esta entrada?
                        </div>
                            
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="return cerrar_modal()">
                            <i class="fas fa-arrow-left"></i> Volver
                        </button>
                    
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btnTest">
                            <i class="fas fa-minus-circle"></i> Sí, inactivar {{ object }}</strong>
                        </button> 
                            
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Y así llamo al modal en la plantilla base:

```
<section class="content">
              <div class="container-fluid">
                {% block content %}
                
                {% endblock content %}

                <div class="modal fade" id="popup">

                </div>

              </div>
          </section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error estaba en los scripts de máscaras mi archivo base:

```
<!-- Mascaras -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.10/jquery.mask.js"></script>
```

Pues estaba 'sobreescribiendo' mi archivo de jquery y este es un causal del error mostrado. La solución finalmente fue eliminar este llamado.